# How to get all duplicates with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get all duplicates in list. LIst like {1,2,3,4,3} and result must be {3,3}.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, since you need the list to contain all the duplicate items (i.e. two 3's in your example):

```
var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 };
var dupes = items.Where(searchFor => items.FindAll(item => item == searchFor).Count > 1);
```

Comment: FindAll does not Exist. There is Find but with exception: "IOrderedEnumerable <MyClass> "does not contain a definition for" Find "and could not find the" Find "extension method that takes the type" IOrderedEnumerable <MyClass> "as the first argument (perhaps using the using directive or the assembly reference)"

Comment: You said you were using a `List`, which does not implement `IOrderedEnumerable`. What type are you *really* using?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to simplify question. I really use massive:             PaidService[] array = { //some instances(id,name,cost)}; and must get name of servises with same cost

Comment: Ok. I guess you'll have to ask the question more precisely...this one is closed now and can't be answered.

Comment: Also, using a `List<PaidService>` is better than a `PaidService[]` 99% of the time, with the added bonus that you can use the answer above to solve your problem.